# Proving that $\{\tau_n=\infty\}=\left\{\int_0^TX_u^2\,du\le n\right\} $

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ probability space, $\mathbb F=\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ a right-continous and complete filtration (right continuity means that $\mathcal F_t=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\mathcal F_{t+\epsilon}$ and completness means that for every $A\in\mathcal A$ with $P(A)=0$, every $\mathcal F_t$ contains every $B$, with $B\subseteq A$).

Let's consider $X\in M^2_{loc}[0,T]$, i.e. $X:\Omega\times[0,T]\to\Bbb R$ is progressively measurable and $\int_0^TX_u^2\,du<+\infty$ a.s.

Define then for every $n\in\Bbb N$
$$
\tau_n:=\inf\left\{t\in[0,T]\;:\;\int_0^tX_u^2\,du>n\right\}
$$
with the convention that $\inf\emptyset=+\infty$.
So $\tau_n$ is a sequence of $\Bbb F$-stopping times.

I have to prove that
$$
\{\tau_n=\infty\}=\left\{\int_0^TX_u^2\,du\le n\right\}
$$
Now $\subseteq$ is clear; in order to prove the inverse inclusion I tried to prove that 
$$
\{\tau_n<\infty\}\subseteq\left\{\int_0^TX_u^2\,du> n\right\}
$$
but I have some problems: I argued as follows
\begin{align*}
\{\tau_n<\infty\}
&=\{\tau_n\le T\}=\{\tau_n< T\}\cup \{\tau_n= T\}
\end{align*}
and clearly
$$
\{\tau_n< T\}\subseteq\left\{\int_0^TX_u^2\,du> n\right\}
$$
but 
$$
\{\tau_n= T\}=\left\{\int_0^TX_u^2\,du=n\right\}\;.
$$
Thus I proved that
$$
\{\tau_n<\infty\}\subseteq\left\{\int_0^TX_u^2\,du\ge n\right\}
$$
which is not the inclusion I wanted beacuse of that $\ge$ instead of a $>$.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in $\{\tau_n= T\}=\left\{\int_0^TX_u^2\,du=n\right\}\;$. This identity would be correct if the infimum defining $\tau_n$ was not over the compact set $[0,T]$. In the present case we have that actually $\{\tau_n= T\}=\emptyset$. With this fix, the rest of your proof is correct.

Edit on why $\{\tau_n= T\}=\emptyset$:

For $\tau_n=T$ to happen, the set $A=\left\{t\in[0,T]\;:\;\int_0^tX_u^2\,du>n\right\}$ must be non-empty. In particular, $\int_0^TX_u^2\,du>n$, and by continuity, $t\in A$ for some $t<T$, so that even $\tau_n< T$, which is impossible. Thus $\{\tau_n= T\}=\emptyset$.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I have a doubt: $t\mapsto\int_0^tX_u^2\,du$ is a continous map thus it should be $\int_0^{\tau_n}X_u^2\,du=n$. Why is this false?

Comment: I have added an answer to this as an edit. Hope it's clearer now!

Comment: Thanks Martin... I'm preparing my Stochastic Analysis exam and I'm a little bit tired! Thanks again :-)